# Looping over a stream in Scala

Tags: scala

Here is a Scala class:

```
class CustomizedStream[K,V](private val queue: BlockingQueue[FetchedDataChunk],
                    FooTimeoutMs: Int,
                    private val keyDecoder: Decoder[K],
                    private val valueDecoder: Decoder[V],
                    val clientId: String)
  extends Iterable[MessageAndMetadata[K,V]] with java.lang.Iterable[MessageAndMetadata[K,V]] {
...
}
```

and in Java code

```
 Map<String, List<FoStream<byte[], byte[]>>> foStreams = consumer
            .createMessageStreams(topicCount);
    List<CustomizedStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerStreams.get(topic);
for (final CustomizedStream stream : streams) {
        FoIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next().message());
        }
    }
```

How to rewrite the above Java code in Scala? I try the for(stream <- streams) and get

```
value foreach is not a member of java.util.List[CustomizedStream(Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]]
```

Łukasz suggests a solution as the following:

```
for{
  stream <- streams.asScala
  m <- stream
}{
   println(m)
}
```

I can't see any outputs and the same for

```
for{
  stream <- streams.asScala
} {
    println(stream)  // <- this line shows up 
    for(m <- stream){
      println(m)
    }
}
```

and the same for

```
val foStreams = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCount);
val streams : java.util.List[KafkaStream[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]]= foStreams.get(topic);
val itr = streams.iterator()
while(itr.hasNext){
  val a = itr.next()
  println(a)  // <- can see this line
  val itr2 =   a.iterator()
  while(itr2.hasNext()) {
    println(itr2.next()) // but not this line
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like something could be wrong with `CustomizedStream` class. Try to include the code in your post. It should contain only what is essential to reproduce the issue. Actually the useful mcve in this case should contain basic `CustomizedStream` as well as code that constructs `streams` list and objects it contains.

Comment: The Java code works. So, it might be wrong on the conversion.

Comment: My guess is that scala `iterator` method is shadowed by java one as you implement both traits, but noone is able to test your code as you don't provide it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am not even able to create a class that implements both java and scala Iterable...

Comment: The reason I don't provide the whole code is that the related code is from a library we don't own. Too many related library code. In the debugging mood, the second tier data is shown as "Collecting data...".

Comment: I don't ask you to provide the code of library that you don't own, but to reimplement it, or rather only minimum code that allows to reproduce the issue, so the problem still orccurs but without the code that is not needed to reproduce the issue. Again, see what mcve is. There is no way for me to paste the code into IDE and see that it actually does not work and try to fix it.

Comment: I add two lines of code although I can't see how it will help you. It basically is retrieving data from a map. And I can't see the data since it is a stream.

Comment: I didn't think right yesterday. The behavior is right. The stream is open for incoming data. Not a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to loop over stream here but over a `java.util.List` that contains `CustomizedStream`. What it contains is irrelevant.

The obvious approach would be to convert the java list to scala seq.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val streams: java.util.List[CustomizedStream[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]] = ???

for (stream <- streams.asScala) {
  // .. code
}
```

as the `CustomizedStream` implements scala `Iterable` you can simplify your java code to

```
for {
  stream <- streams.asScala
  m <- stream
} { 
  println(m.message)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Java converters is needed. I try the simplified the version and it doesn't seem to be looping for ever. The following code seems to be working val itr = streams.iterator()
    while(itr.hasNext){
      println(itr.next())

    }

Comment: The second looping isn't working. The following code yields the same result as looping for ever;    val itr = streams.iterator()
    while(itr.hasNext){
      val itr2 = itr.next().iterator()
      while(itr2.hasNext()) {
        println(itr2.next())
      }

    }

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you update your question and provide MCVE, show the code that doesn't work and explain what you expect.